# How to check my house for termites?

Tags: extermination

I may just be paranoid so I don't want to call out an exterminator, or buy a bunch of stuff I don't need.

1. How to I tell if I have termites?
2. Are there preventative measures I *should* take even if I don't have them?
3. If I do have them can I kill them myself or do I need to hire and exterminator?

Answer (score 2):

Mud tubes around the base of the house are a sure sign of ground dwelling termites, and pinholes in woodwork are the handywork of the airborne variety. Termites need to be handled by professionals.

Answer (score 2):

Here's another post with good tips: [Any words of advice on dealing with termites?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/any-words-of-advice-on-dealing-with-termites)

In terms of prevention, you can pickup a package of traps at the local hardware store and install them yourself. You should also avoid the ground coming into contact with surfaces that termites can infest.  That means you should keep mulch well below any siding and fences, keep wood piles away from the building, and make sure that bushes and trees are trimmed back.