# Is it safe to use Biflex TC for termite control in my house?

Tags: pest-control

Today I found that my house is infested with termites. It's really scary the way they affect wooden stuff inside the house.

I contacted a few agencies here in my city (Ahmedabad, India). The one that seemed good said that they use [Biflex TC](http://www.google.com/#sclient=psy&hl=en&safe=off&source=hp&q=biflex+tc&pbx=1&oq=biflex+tc&aq=f&aqi=p-p2g3&aql=&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=510043l510242l6l510370l2l2l2l0l0l0l0l0ll0l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.&fp=58935e0d63e81eca&biw=1280&bih=666) to deal with the termites. I wanted to know if anyone here has any idea whether the chemical has been or is probably going to be banned from any countries due to its effects on humans.

I may sound paranoid but I am concerned about my family's health. If the chemical has any adverse effects on human health then I would definitely look for some other option.

PS - I found a [termite related question](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5809/any-words-of-advice-on-dealing-with-termites) asked earlier on the site but it had no mention of Biflex TC.

Answer (score 3):

Some searching shows that the active ingredient is called [bifenthrin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bifenthrin).  It has been banned for use as a pesticide in the EU.

Some more links that you may find helpful:

- US National Pesticide Information Center: http://npic.orst.edu/factsheets/biftech.pdf
- EU European Food Safety Authority:  http://www.efsa.europa.eu/en/efsajournal/doc/186r.pdf

They have a lot of information, so they should help you decide whether or not it's right for you and your family.

Comment: Thanks. After reading the US National Pesticide Information Center's pdf, I feel it's safe to use it.